# When does Xoti first mention her dreams?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

At what point does Xoti first mention that she's having nightmares?

Starting with Maje Island I have had conversations with her about her nightmares as if the protagonist already knows about them, but her dialogue before this never mentioned her having nightmares, there was no setup for the problem. Now I'm wondering if this is an oversight from the writers/narrative designers, if an initial conversation failed to trigger, or if it was mentioned in passing and I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can talk about her nightmares almost as soon as she joins your party, even while she doesn't mention them directly to you until much later. However, there are a few instances where she describes her nightmares in the background as a random party banter/monologue - for example, she says that she has seen a priest on fire.